# Programmatically trigger Show all objects

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I load two large models. The first one loads completely, but the second model does not show all objects. After I select "Show all objects" from context menu, the viewer refreshes and shows all objects.

Is there a way to trigger "Show all objects" with javascript? Or some other way to refresh the viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing this behavior on my side, maybe I am not testing with models large enough or the issue is specific to some of your models. If you have the models on A360, you can give it a try in my forge demo sample at https://forge.autodesk.io.

Simply authorize the app and should should see your models, double click an item to insert into the scene.

The first suggestion would be:

```
viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)
```

You can also try the command that is fired by the contextmenu:

```
viewer.showAll()
```